# Show set A is open (metric spaces)

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be the set defined as

$$A= \left\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\sin(x)+x \cos^2(x)< \frac{1}{2}\right\} $$

Show that A is open.

Comment: The function $f(x) := \sin(x) + x\cos(x)^2$ is continuous.  We have $A = f^{-1}([0,1/2))$, so $A$ is the preimage of an open set.  Therefore $A$ is open.  Or are you trying to show that the function is continuous?

Comment: No I was trying to show it was open by using the basic definition of open sets such that Let (X, d) be a metric space. A set U ⊆ X is open if
∀x∈U ∃r>0:Br(x)⊆U. However noting your comment that helps me out, many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ be the function defined by $\displaystyle f(x)=\sin(x)+x\cos(x^2)$. The function $f$ is continuous and $\left(-\infty,\frac12\right)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$. Therefore, since $A=f^{-1}\left(-\infty,\frac12\right)$, $A$ is open.